# Is there any algorithm to find the global minimum for the quasi-convex optimization?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima, non-convex-optimization, global-optimization

Consider the following optimization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & f(x)\\ \text{subject to} & g(x,y) \leq 0\end{array}$$

where the objective function $f$ is linear. When I fix  $y=y_0$, the region $\{(x,y_0)\in(\mathbb{R^n,R}) \mid g(x,y_0)\leq 0\}$ is convex, but $\{(x,y)\in(\mathbb{R^n,R}) \mid g(x,y) \leq 0\}$ is not convex.

Is there any algorithm to find the global minimum?

PS: Using a local minimum optimization algorithm(SQP), I find the outcome is always equal to the global minimum. I guess that the  objective function $f(x)$ only has one local minimum, but I dont't know how to prove it.

Comment: Is $y$ one of the optimization variables? When you write $\{x\mid g(x,y) \leq 0\}$, do you really mean $\{(x,y) \mid g(x,y) \leq 0\}$?

Comment: Assuming the answer to littleO is “yes” then the answer to yours is “there is no known algorithm.” If you make f=0 and g(x,y)=h(y) for any arbitrary h, the problem reduces to finding y to satisfy arbitrary constraints $h(y)\leq0$.

Comment: Such an algorithm could find the global minimum of any function $h$, by minimizing $x$ subject to $(x-h(y))^2\le0$.

Comment: Yes, $y$ is also one of the optimization variables. – Zhou 10 mins ago    Delete